# using objects in different forms

Tags: c#, object

I need help to be able to use an object from one form to the other one. Here is the code I have:

In form1:

```cs
Refuge refuge = new Refuge("Iberville", chemin + imgIberville, 1, 35, 35);
this.Hide();
reservation_form.Show();
```

In form2 (reservation_form):

```cs
labelNomRefuge.Text = // here I want to get the first parameter from the object
```

And here is my class:

```cs
public class Refuge
{
    // propriétés de la classe
    public string nomRefuge { get; set; }
    public string chemImage { get; set; }
    public int numRefuge { get; set; }
    public int capacite { get; set; }
    public int placesDispo { get; set; }

    //constructeur avec paramètres
    public Refuge(string pNomRefuge, string pChemImage, int pNumRefuge, int pCapacite, int pPlacesDispo)
    {
        nomRefuge = pNomRefuge;
        chemImage = pChemImage;
        numRefuge = pNumRefuge;
        capacite = pCapacite;
        placesDispo = pPlacesDispo;
    }
```

But in form2, object is apparently do not exist.

Comment: store this object in session and use it another form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

In form2 add this variable:

```
public Refuge refuge;
```

Then when you display the form:

```
 reservation_form.refuge = this.refuge   // assign a reference to the object
 reservation_form.Show();
```

Comment: Refuge refuge = new Refuge("Iberville", chemin + imgIberville, 1, 35, 35);
                this.Hide();
                reservation_form.refuge = this.refuge;
                reservation_form.Show();           


Form 2 :
            labelNomRefuge.Text = refuge.nomRefuge;

Comment: @MathieuGoulet - Please edit your question by adding a `----` at the bottom and then add the modified code for us to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your reservation form

```
class Reservation_Form
{
     // ...
     private Refuge _refuge;
     public Refuge Refuge
     {
        get
        {
            return _refuge;
        }
        set
        {
            _refuge = value;
            this.labelNomRefuge.Text = _refuge.RefugeName;
        }
     }
     // ..
}
```

Then you can call it as so:

```
Refuge refuge = new Refuge("Iberville", chemin + imgIberville, 1, 35, 35);
reservation_form.Refuge = refuge;
this.Hide();
reservation_form.Show();
```